# Tensor troubles: Finding product of fields isomorphic to a given tensor product of field extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, tensor-products, universal-property

I am looking for a hint on the following problem: Find fields $K_1$ and $K_2$ with 
$$
\mathbb{Q}{(\sqrt{3})}\otimes_\mathbb{Q}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})\cong K_1\times K_2
$$
My thoughts were to try and use the universal property of tensor products, by maybe defining map $(a,b)\mapsto ab$ from 
$\mathbb{Q}{(\sqrt{3})}\times\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})\to \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})$ which would induce a linear map on the tensor product. The problem here is this is not (at least obviously to me) a product of fields, nor an isomorphism.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you know that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}] \simeq \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-3)$. Also, for fields (and for more general rings too I think, but maybe there are some conditions on the rings) $K[x] \otimes L = L[x] $. Hope that helps!
Edited for more details:
I believe this is correct: Let $K=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]$. Then we want $K[x]/(x^4-3) = K[x]/(x^2-\sqrt{3}) \oplus K[x]/(x^2+\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(3^{\frac{1}{4}}) \oplus \mathbb{Q}(3^{\frac{1}{4}})$.

Comment: yeah this is right, sorry I missed your edit. I just realized this as well and was about to provide a a nearly identical answer just quotienting in a different order. Probably worth mentioning CRT where you use it though. Also using that $x^4-\sqrt{3}$ splits into quadratics over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: ********$x^4-3$